# xslt 1.0 rewrite values of a node according to a map

Tags: xslt

While transforming a document, I need to 'look up' certain node contents in a 'map', and write those values.

I inlined my 'map' in the transformation.

```
<xsl:variable name="inlinedmap">
    <kat id="stuff">value</kat>
    <!-- ... -->
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="map" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:variable[@name='inlinedmap']" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/*/foo">
        <!-- 'bar' contents should equal to contents of 'kat' -->
        <xsl:variable name="g" select="$map/key[.=bar]"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$g != ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="$g/@id"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                ERROR
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm always getting ERROR value.
I can't put map value's into attributes, because they contain letters that get escaped.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few problems here:

- You seem to be looking for `key` elements in your variable, but they're called `kat` there (typo?)
- You seem to be trying to reference the `bar` child of the context node inside the loop, but you need to use `current()` to do that
- You should create this map as elements in your own namespace instead of an `xsl:variable`

Here's a complete example. This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="my">
    <my:vars>
        <kat id="stuff">value</kat>
        <!-- ... -->
    </my:vars>
    <xsl:variable name="map" select="document('')/*/my:vars/*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/foo">
            <!-- 'bar' contents should equal to contents of 'kat' -->
            <xsl:variable name="g" select="$map[.=current()/bar]"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$g != ''">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$g/@id"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    ERROR
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this input:

```
<root>
    <foo><bar>value</bar></foo>
    <foo><bar>value1</bar></foo>
    <foo><bar>value2</bar></foo>
    <foo><bar>value3</bar></foo>
</root>
```

Produces this output (one match):

```
stuff
ERROR
ERROR
ERROR
```

Comment: @ŁukaszGruner: This is as informative as "Looked in the window, it is still raining". You haven't provided in the first place a source XML document. Nor have you provided a complete transformation. Not to mention the wanted result... If people can't repro your problem, it might be just a product of your imagination! Please, edit and improve your question. Also, please, pay more respect to the rare few brave people people who might dare and try to guess what actually you were meaning.

Comment: worked properly, the main issue (except stuff explained in the answer) was encoding of my map